# How to create a view that separate dates in two fields by their type in SQL

Tags: sql, view

Im trying to use this table Alarms:

```
ID        CarID  Location           Date          Type
897847    7198      3       2019-11-26 11:54:54    20
897852    7198      3       2019-11-26 11:55:14    21
1001987   7198      3       2019-12-10 16:08:28    20
1001988   7198      3       2019-12-10 16:08:38    21
```

To create a view that separates the Date by their type (20 or 21) and using timediff to calculate the difference between then and respecting same carID and Location, to get something like this:

```
ID        CarID  Location      InicialDate(20)        EndDate(21)          Total
897847    7198      3       2019-11-26 11:54:54   2019-11-26 11:55:14     00:00:20
1001987   7198      3       2019-12-10 16:08:28   2019-12-10 16:08:38     00:00:10
```

There will be cases that will appear dates with Type 20 2,3 or 4 times before appear a date with Type 21, so i need to always get the first date Type 20 with first date type 21, second type 20 with second type 21 and so on always respecting same carID and Location, cannot be same carid and different location and vice versa.

Any ideas that can help me? Thank you

Comment: You should probably update your sample data and results to show the special cases that you  mention at the end of your question, so it is clearer what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

### **For SQL Server:-**

**For reference [Check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6cd5d702ce2883008eb5bd29d201316)**

```
;with cte as (select dense_rank() over( order by CarID,Location,cast(Date as date)) dr,
* from tbl),cte1 as(
select dr,min(ID) ID,CarID,Location,type,min(date) min_date,max(date) max_date from cte
group by dr,CarID,Location,type)
select min(ID) ID,CarID,Location,min(min_date) [InicialDate(20)],max(max_date)[EndDate(21)],
datediff(second,min(min_date),max(max_date)) total
from cte1
group by CarID,Location,dr
```

### **For MySql:-**

**For reference [Check Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9ced38ae4cd443531949d23bab4873e)**

```
select min(ID) ID,CarID,Location,min(min_date) as `InicialDate(20)`,max(max_date)as `EndDate(21)`,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,min(min_date),max(max_date))as  total
from (
select dr,min(ID) as ID,CarID,Location,type,min(date)as  min_date,max(date) as max_date from (select dense_rank() over( order by CarID,Location,cast(Date as date)) as dr,
ID,CarID,Location,Date,Type from tbl)as cte
group by dr,CarID,Location,type) as cte1
group by CarID,Location,dr;
```

Comment: unfortunately the mysql running don't support CTEs and i can't update, i'll have to try another aproach. Thank you anyway.